# Robocopy: copy files preserving folder structure but adding a subfolder

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, robocopy

I need to copy a folder which contains subfolders with files to a shared folder on another machine. During that, the script should create a custom subfolder in each destination folder and place files there.

I hope this example clarifies the task:

1. **For the following source folder:**

   ```
   --Logs
   ----Application
   ------Service
   --------Log1.txt
   --------Log2.txt
   ------WebSite
   --------Log1.txt
   --------Log2.txt
   ```
2. **Destination folder should be created in the following way:**

   ```
   --Logs
   ----Application
   ------Service
   --------Machine1
   ----------Log1.txt
   ----------Log2.txt
   ------WebSite
   --------Machine1
   ----------Log1.txt
   ----------Log2.txt
   ```

As you see at the bottom level subfolders `Machine1` have been created.
Can you please provide an example of PowerShell script that can do this?

I investigated input parameters in `ROBOCOPY` command. It seems it doesn't allow me to do this straightforwardly.

Also I know that I can simply iterate through all folder structure, create required sub folders and copy files to each subfolder, but it seems to be a too 'long' way. So, I want to know if I'm missing anything. Maybe there is a better/smarter way to do this.

Comment: Did you attempt anything yourself? Or do you want us to just do your work for you?

Comment: Of course the work for me would be the best my present today (I'm joking).
I've added my effort to the question.

Comment: Right... I think I follow now. You have a solution but want to know if it could improved? That's fair enough, but it will easier to see your code and then see what could be done. You have a 1.6k rep with SO, you should know the drill about sharing code :)

Comment: I don't have any code yet. I want to make sure that there is a better way to achieve my goal without iterating folder structure before writing any code. Also, I don't expect writing code from your side, I just need an idea how to do that in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Did this quick and dirty code... still iterates though the folder though...

```
$orgLoc = "test"
$desLoc = "dest"

Copy-Item -Path $orgLoc -Destination $desLoc -Recurse
$stuff = Get-ChildItem -Path $desLoc -Recurse
foreach($thing in $stuff){
    if($thing.Extension -eq ".txt"){
        $newDir = $thing.DirectoryName + "\Machine1"
        if(!(Test-Path $newDir)){
            New-Item -Path $newDir -ItemType Directory
        }
        Move-Item -Path $thing.FullName -Destination $newDir
    }
}
```